# Recognize "apple-touch-icon" with htaccess password protection

Tags: php, ios, iphone, .htaccess, apple-touch-icon

The question: How can I use a custom iPhone home screen icon while securing my website with .htaccess?

The setup:

- PHP PaaS
- Rudimentary password protection using .htaccess and .htpasswd
- Simple website built using [Wikitten](https://github.com/victorstanciu/Wikitten)

The problem: I would like to see my custom "apple-touch-icon" when I put a bookmark of my website onto my iPhone home screen using the "Add to Home Screen" function in mobile Safari. Unfortunately, when I enable "require valid-user" in the .htaccess file, the iPhone does not see the icon and instead uses a generic image. When I disable password protection in .htaccess, the icon is recognized, but I really need some sort of password protection and I hope to continue using the current method.

Any help is appreciated; thanks,
Mitch

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this guide](http://perishablepress.com/enable-file-or-directory-access-to-your-htaccess-password-protected-site/) which had me add the following lines of code to the bottom of my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(path\to\file\.ext)$" allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

I assume this method requires the icon to be named `apple-touch-icon.png` since Safari won't have access to any linking in the HTML. Ergo, for my site I specifically used:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(apple-touch-icon\.png)$" allow
```

Where in the root of my website lives a 180px version of my desired icon.

Comment: Normally name is `apple-touch-icon-180x180.png`. The browser tries with sizes would like to use in order of preference. the element’s size defaults to 60 x 60

Answer (score 0):

Do not protect the whole site, but all that is in a directory (Even if almost all of the site).

This way, you can show a home page, with explanations for those wishing to access the site.
And apple-touch-icon...

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out.  By the way, you must offer more than one icon for different Apple devices: https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html